# Error while npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, dependency-injection, npm, ionic2

I always get this error - while creating a new project or installing a new npm packages

There's a conflict between packages or something else - any help?

[image]

Comment: Are you running npm install as root/admin? If not, try that.

Comment: You mean run as administrator , Ok - I'll try

Comment: Yes, now that I notice you are on Windows, that is right.

Comment: Yes windows , but did not work as admin - it's about conflict between packages and depedency injection - not about the admin role

Comment: RXJS latest version is 5.2.0. Have you tried adding that to the package.json rather than the beta?

Comment: I tried , also RXJS 5.2.0 not satisfy

Comment: what version of RXJS is shown in your package.json? can you add your package.json to the question?

Comment: Upadting NodeJS - solved the problem .. thanks guys

Comment: Could you please put your answer to what worked. Also, which version of NodeJS?